# Adding view controller in scrollview

Tags: swift, scrollview, viewcontroller

I am currently working on an app that has been developed using storyboards.

I am trying to add a view controller programmatically into a paging scroll view at the beginning before 2 other views that are already added within the storyboard.

The view controller gets added but the width is slightly larger and goes across into the middle view.

```
let vc = Vc()
scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to assign a `contentSize` to the `scrollview` and a position for the `frame` of the `ViewController`

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2 * view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    
let frameVC = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        
vc.view.frame = frameVC

vc.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Note that you have to change the `frameVC` to match your requirements

#### Swift 5 sytax update

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2 * view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    
let frameVC = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        
vc.view.frame = frameVC

vc.willMove(toParent: self)
addChild(vc)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

*Note: Frames vs Constraint layout*

Instead of using a frame you can also use create a constraint layout to add a `UIView` to a `UIScrollView`

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2 * view.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    
scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)

vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// add constrains here

vc.willMove(toParent: self)
addChild(vc)
vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```